# Why does Altium not permit changing net names from schematic view?

Tags: altium

Here is a short snippet from the schematic view showing the righ click menu from a net and the net properties:

[image]

Altium shows Physical name and Net name for the net. However, there is no way to modify them in here. This is quite puzzling. This brings me to these questions:

1. What is the difference between the Physical name and Net name for this net?
2. How do I modify the net name to an arbitrary value from the schematic window?

Note: I am using Altium 22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical net names are local to a schematic so they can vary from physical if you are using a hierarchical design.

To modify the net name, drop a net label onto the wire. Some folks like to give a sensible name to every single distinct net in a design.

Comment: I see, so it is not possible to give a name without using a net label. What do you mean by physical name and why should it be different from the one in the schematic?

Comment: Physical name is what is used in routing. If you only use flat schematics the two will be the same.